# Question about AnimationEvent.Time in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, events

I am quite new in Unity and I have a simple question regarding Animation events.
In my code snipet I have the public variables - I noticed that I can't reference an AnimationEvent - and some simple stuff to do with them.

```
public GameObject completeLevelUI; // a panel
public Text endUI; // the text on the panel that show your success or fail
public AnimationEvent nextSceneEvent; // AnimatonEvent in the animation of the panel above

public void GameOver() { nextSceneEvent.time = 2; completeLevelUI.SetActive(true); endUI.text = "LEVEL\nFAILED"; }

public void GameWon() { nextSceneEvent.time = 6; completeLevelUI.SetActive(true); endUI.text = "LEVEL\nCOMPLETED"; }

public void LoadEnd() { SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1); }
```

The AnimationEvent's target method is `LoadEnd()`.
**The default firing time is 1.5 seconds and the code won't change it.**

The reason why I need different fire times can't be seen in the shared code - it is not important now. I figured out some other ways to solve it, I am just curious why it isn't working.
I have tried to change the activating and the time setting code piece but it is the same.

Somehow I have to reference the AnimationEvent? Is it a problem that this script is called multiple times, even from places where there is no AnimationEvent - I didn't receive any exceptions during my examination.

Any ideas? Thanks for helping!

Comment: What are you trying to do with the animation event? It fires and triggers your code. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: When the event is fired an other scene is loaded (a kind of thanks for playing scene). And I want that next scene to load in x seconds depending on a victory or death.

Comment: But the main point here - you can't see it in the published code - that it tinkers a bit with volume. Maybe I will do it with an Invoke...

Comment: Then i think youre going about it the wrong way. On fight over. Set something you can test that means your event code just reads if (get fight result == win) load win rlse load lose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have an animation playing and at the end you want to trigger the new scene.
You can use different approaches.

First, you add the animation event directly to the animation clip and you set the method in the inspector. The method has to be on a component attached to the same game object as the animation.

Second, you launch the animation and wait for the end of it to call the method:

```
void EndProcess()
{
     StartCoroutine(EndProcessSequence());
}

IEnumerator EndProcessSequence()
{
    Animation anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
    anim.Play("animName");
    yield return new WaitWhile(()=> anim.isPlaying);
    LoadNewScene();
}
```

Here' s a reusable version

```
IEnumerator EndProcessSequence(string animName, Action onComplete)
    {
        Animation anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
        anim.Play(animName);
        yield return new WaitWhile(()=> anim.isPlaying);
        onComplete?.Invoke();
    }
```